# how to prevent Same Activity reload again

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have a simple android activity, which has a button and the following scenario:

**On first time button click instead of starting a new activity it reloads the same activity**. **However, on the second time same button click it works fine**. 
Can you please help me how to resolve this issue. The code I tried is below:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ServiceRequest.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }

        });
    }
}
```

//Next Activity

```
public class ServiceRequest extends BaseActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.service_request, frameLayout);

        Button booking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.booking);

        booking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Intent i = new Intent(ServiceRequest.this, Form.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();


            }

        });


    }

}
```

// Manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

         />
 <activity android:name=".ServiceRequest" />
```

Comment: show some code     ...

Comment: i have already told u code are simple there is no complications.

Comment: also please include the manifest tag for the same activity

Comment: plz also provide ServiceRequest.class details. also.. the manifest file

Comment: See the updated code ..

Answer (score 0):

Atleast provide your code.
Anyway, You will need to pass the parameters carefully

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      // add flags or extras, if any
      startActivity(intent);   
      finish();   
}
```

Comment: There is no parameter requirement